# JSONObject.put(string,string) not working

Tags: android, json, android-studio

```
String value = myInput.getText().toString();
```

I want to put string value into `JSONObject.put("STRING",value)` method but it's not working..

See the attached screen shot and tell how to resolve this.

[image]

Comment: use try catch for that

Comment: you forgot to attach screenshot.

Comment: My question is not about what error is coming..

Comment: why try catch is compulsory for that

Comment: because may be Exception comes so catch block handle

Comment: use `jsonObject.accumulate("{key}","{value}");`

Answer (score 5):

Add `try.. catch`

```
String data = "";
String val = "hello";
            try {
                JSONObject j = new JSONObject(data);
                j.put("VAL", val);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: because may be Exception comes so catch block handle

Answer (score 4):

You should wrap the code inside **try-catch**

```
try {
    JSONObject j = new JSONObject(data);
} catch (JSONException e) {        
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Why try-catch is compulsary??**

There are 2 kinds of exceptions: **Checked** and **Unchecked**.

1. **Checked exception** can be considered one that is found by the compiler, and the compiler knows that it has a chance to occur, so you need to catch or throw it.
2. **Unchecked exception** is a Runtime Exception which means these are exceptional conditions that are internal to the application, and that the application usually cannot anticipate or recover from.

JSONException is a type of Checked exception. Checked exceptions needs to be handled at compile time itself.

**new JSONObject(data)** will throw JSONException if the parse fails or doesn't yield a JSONObject. So it is recommended to wrap it inside a try-catch block at  compile time itself & the underlying IDE will show an error message for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Put your code in `try.. catch` block because may be Exception occur

```
 try{
         JSONObject params = new JSONObject(data);  
    }
 catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```